# Component Based Architecture Using Interface Default Methods

Tags: oop, design-patterns, c#-8.0

Is using interface default methods implementation (like we have in C#8) alongside the component based architecture can be considered best practice?

For example suppose we define:

```
interface Walkable
{
   int PositionX {get; set;}
   int PositionY {get; set;}

   void Move(Direction d)
   {
      // some logic
   }
}

class Player : Walkable
{
  // ...
}
```

We can easily add the walking functionality to more game objects (e.g NPCs) without duplicating code on one hand, and add more behavioral components to the Player (like Attackable for instance) on the other hand.

Comment: so, to get a feelf or it, just use an ECS system for this - unity!   Have a game object.  Add behaviors. ("can walk" "explodes when hit" "dances" etc.)

Comment: @Fattie I think the real question here is if the "interface default methods" feature is relevant here. In my opinion no, because each component should encapsulate sate (e.g. for timer), which interface doesnt support.

Comment: that sounds very sensible, @barak1412